# Call to MATLAB function in a Python program

Tags: python, matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling MATLAB functions from python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883189/calling-matlab-functions-from-python)

I wrote MATLAB code (that easily could be implemented as a function) that convert a series of [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) files to [AVI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Video_Interleave) files. I want a Python program to call to this program/function. How do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [mlabwrap](http://mlabwrap.sourceforge.net/). Mlabwrap is a high-level [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29)-to-[MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB)® bridge that lets MATLAB look like a normal Python library.