# Calling MATLAB functions from python

Tags: python, matlab, visual-c++

Is it possible to run MATLAB functions from within Python?
I search the internet, I could only find PyMat. The bad thing is the compiled version only supports Python2.2 and I am using 2.6. So I tried to download the source code, so I can compile it for myself. But I cannot compile it, VC++ express seems not to have the necessary functionalities to compile it. Does anyone have the compile version for PC?
or any substitutes for PyMat?
Thanks

Comment: numpy is your friend when matlab disappoint you

Answer (score 26, accepted):

PyMat looks like it's been abandoned.

I'm assuming you are on windows so you could always do the simplest approach and use Matlab's COM interface:

```
>>> import win32com.client
>>> h = win32com.client.Dispatch('matlab.application')
>>> h.Execute ("plot([0 18], [7 23])")
>>> h.Execute ("1+1")
u'\nans =\n\n     2\n\n'
```

More info [here](http://www.system.nada.kth.se/unix/software/matlab/senaste/techdoc/matlab_external/ch07cl24.html)

Comment: Hey, is there a way to get the Python script to halt if a MATLAB command produces an error or even print out the error? I noticed that Python ignores errors by default and moves on through the script. -Thanks

Comment: is the run statement of matlab to run a script executable using this command?

Answer (score 33):

I know this is an old question and has been answered. But I was looking for the same thing (for the Mac) and found that there are quite a few options with different methods of interacting with matlab and different levels of maturity. Here's what I found:

### pymat

A low level interface to Matlab using the matlab engine (`libeng`) for communication (basically a library that comes with matlab). The module has to be compiled and linked with libeng.

http://pymat.sourceforge.net
Last updated: 2003

### pymat2

A somewhat short lived continuation of the pymat development. Seems to work on windows (including 64bit), linux and mac (with some changes).

https://code.google.com/p/pymat2/
Last updated: 2012

### mlabwrap

A high level interface that also comes as a module which needs compilation and linking against  `libeng`. It exposes Matlab functions to python so you can do fun stuff like

`mlab.plot(x, y, 'o')`

http://mlabwrap.sourceforge.net
Last updated: 2009

### mlab

A repackaging effort of mlabwrap. Basically it replaces the c++ code that links against 'libeng' in *mlabwrap* with a python module ([matlabpipe](https://code.google.com/p/danapeerlab/source/browse/trunk/freecell/depends/common/python/matlabpipe.py)) that communicates with matlab through a pipe. The main advantage of this is that it doesn't need compilation of any kind.

Unfortunately the package currently has a couple of bugs and doesn't seem to work on the mac at all. I reported a few of them but gave up eventually. Also, be prepared for lots of trickery and a bunch of pretty ugly hacks if you have to go into the source code ;-) If this becomes more mature it could be one of the best options.

https://github.com/ewiger/mlab
last update: 2013

### pymatlab

A newer package (2010) that also interacts with Matlab through `libeng`. Unlike the other packages this one loads the engine library through [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) thus no compilation required. Its not without flaws but still being maintained and the (64bit Mac specific) issues I found should be easy enough to fix.
(**edit 2014-05-20**: it seems those issues have already been fixed in the source so things should be fine with 0.2.4)

http://pymatlab.sourceforge.net
last update: 2014

### python-matlab-bridge

Also a newer package that is still actively maintained. Communicates with Matlab through some sort of socket. Unfortunately the exposed functions are a bit limited. I couldn't figure out how to invoke a function that takes structs as parameters. Requires zmq, pyzmq and IPython which are easy enough to install.

http://arokem.github.io/python-matlab-bridge
last update: 2014

Comment: +1 for your post. The question is old (as you said) but still relevant. The older answers are outdated since there is a lot of room for improvement in Matlab-Python cross-talk.

Comment: In the spirit of updating older answerd to still relevant questions: Since MATLAB 2014b, Mathworks has included official support for communication between python and matlab: https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-engine-for-python.html

Answer (score 29):

Another option is [`Mlabwrap`](http://mlabwrap.sourceforge.net/):

> Mlabwrap is a high-level python to Matlab® bridge that lets Matlab look like a normal python library.

It works well with numpy arrays.  An example from the home page:

```
>>> from mlabwrap import mlab; from numpy import *
>>> xx = arange(-2*pi, 2*pi, 0.2)
>>> mlab.surf(subtract.outer(sin(xx),cos(xx)))
```

Comment: This [page](http://obasic.net/how-to-install-mlabwrap-on-windows) contains steps to get started with `mlabwrap`

Comment: Note that there is also [``mlab``](https://github.com/ewiger/mlab), "a repackaging effort [of mlabwrap] to make things up-to-date".

Comment: @FlorianBrucker: mlab is somehow broken, at least it does not work for me correctly...

Answer (score 10):

There is a python-matlab bridge which is unique in the sense that Matlab runs in the background so you don't have the startup cost each time you call a Matlab function.
https://github.com/jaderberg/python-matlab-bridge

it's as easy as downloading and the following code:

```
from pymatbridge import Matlab
mlab = Matlab(matlab='/Applications/MATLAB_R2011a.app/bin/matlab')
mlab.start()
res = mlab.run('path/to/yourfunc.m', {'arg1': 3, 'arg2': 5})
print res['result']
```

where the contents of yourfunc.m would be something like this:

```
%% MATLAB
function lol = yourfunc(args)
    arg1 = args.arg1;
    arg2 = args.arg2;
    lol = arg1 + arg2;
end
```

Comment: Max, do you know if there is a way to pass multiple arguments to the matlab function without using a dictionary? That would be very handy! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

see this page: [An Open-Source MATLAB®-to-Python® Compiler](http://ompc.juricap.com/)

Comment: Does it support only up to python 2.6?

Comment: @Francesco, sorry I do not know! I just tried some simple examples about two years ago. I've been using both matlab and python. I just stick to certain data structures, and pass data between them.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to add one more option to the excellent summary by Lukas:

### matlab_wrapper

The advantage of matlab_wrapper is that it is pure Python library and you will not need to compile anything.  Works in GNU/Linux, Windows and OSX.

https://github.com/mrkrd/matlab_wrapper

Disclaimer: I'm the author of matlab_wrapper

Answer (score 3):

You can use the official matlab engine by installing Matlab, then building python engine from its extern files. You can check the guide website below:
---Thanks for the advice in the first comment of this answer ---
the essential step in brief are (On Windows platform, other can checked in the url below):
1. download and then install matlab, the version must be R2014 or later.
2. open a PowerShell window under admin, then:

```
cd "matlabroot\extern\engines\python"
```

3. use command-line below to install:

```
python setup.py install
```

The admin is essential, or you'll fail to build it.

For more information, you can click the official start sheet below:
http://cn.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/install-the-matlab-engine-for-python.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10178966)

Comment: @jezrael Thanks for your advice, I will modify my answer

Answer (score 2):

newer versions of matlab seem to provide a module that allows you to call matlab functions from within python. see [here](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/install-the-matlab-engine-for-python.html) and [here](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-functions-from-python.html).

Comment: I wrote a tutorial of how to use it with classes - http://www.cloud-rocket.com/2016/08/using-matlab-compiled-class-from-python/

Answer (score 2):

2 more options for you to consider:

1. Follow the official MATLAB docs:
   [Create a Python Application with MATLAB Code](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/gs/create-a-python-application-with-matlab-code.html).  This will create a Python library that includes MATLAB runtime which you can call from within your Python code.
2. Run your MATLAB code in [GNU Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) then call it from Python using [Oct2Py](https://blink1073.github.io/oct2py/)

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution from Mathworks.

In your current folder, create a MATLAB script in a file named triarea.m.

```
function a = triarea(b,h)
a = 0.5*(b.* h);
```

Meanwhile, you run the python code as follows,

```
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
eng.addpath('your/code/folders/')
ret = eng.triarea(1.0,5.0)
print(ret)
>>> 2.5
```

Matlab already provides the python module of the engine, to install that you can do the following,

```
cd matlab_root_folder/extern/engines/python
python setup.py install
```

You are all done!
Tips: you need to be careful about the data type, the engine is not friendly with numpy. You need to convert the data first.

```
mat_array = matlab.double(list(my_numpy_array))
eng.my_matlabe_function(mat_array )
```