# How to exit after running matlab script from command line?

Tags: python, matlab

Here is my python code

```
DosCmd = 'matlab -wait -automation -nosplash -r "run \'' + to_run + "'\""
os.system(DosCmd)
curve_file = open('curve/'+str(index)+'.curve','r')
```

I run a .m file in a python script,it works fine but after executing the .m file,it is stuck in `os.system(DosCmd)`.
To make python run the following code,I have to close this window:

[image]

Since this part of code is in a loop,it really disturbs me.
I found someone on the Internet says that matlab can exits automatically after executing the .m file,but mine just doesn't.Will someone tell what I did wrong or what should I do?Thx!

Comment: Try the break keys `CTRL+C`

Comment: Have you tried `exit`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a call to `exit` to the MATLAB code that you execute.

```
DosCmd = 'matlab -wait -automation -nosplash -r "run \'' + to_run + "', exit\""
```

Your quoting looks a little wonky mind you, but you just need to add `, exit` to the end of the command that you pass in the `-r` argument.

By the way, this would be a lot easier with `subprocess` so that you could let `subprocess` do the quoting for you.

```
subprocess.check_call(['matlab', '-wait', '-automation', '-nosplash', 
    '-r', 'run \' + to_run + \', exit'])
```

Comment: Thx,it works!Another question,is there a way that I can "reuse" matlab instead of starting it again and again?

Comment: Well, JonB covered that rather well I think. `mlabwrap` looks good to me. You could use MATLAB as a COM server, but I suspect `mlabwrap` will be much cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

Add the command `exit` to the last line of your script.
The -wait commandline switch means the starter application won't close until matlab exits.   If you are acutally having python do something with the ML output, then -wait is correct, otherwise get rid of the -wait.

Also, are you sure you really want to be launching new matlab session each time in a loop?  Matlab exposes DDE functionality, which would allow you to open one instance and send commands.

Or, you might look at PyMat, or mlabwrap, etc, one of the existing python to matlab bridge libraries.

Comment: thank you!I need "wait" cause the ML output is what I'll deal with next.

Comment: It seems that PyMat and mlabwrap haven't updated for years...But I'm using python3...

Comment: @laike9m: use the COM interface: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2885122/97160 (make sure you have run `matlab -regserver` at least once before)

Comment: @laike9m: just run `matlab.exe -regserver` from the console outside MATLAB. It registers MATLAB as a COM server. You only need to do this once if you havent already