# Starting matlab with win32com Dispatch, application closes itself

Tags: python, matlab, wxpython, win32com

I am trying to start matlab from python, and then execute a really basic test.

```
def execute_matlab_command(command):
    handle = win32com.client.DispatchEx('matlab.application')
    handle.visible = True
    # By using print I know that the handle is valid here
    handle.Execute(command)

execute_matlab_handle("x=32")
```

The code runs fine, but matlab closes before `handle.Execute(command)` is called. Am I missing something here, like an open() or so? I have seen others use (almost) the same code and say that it works fine, cant wrap my head around the problem.

Edit: Matlab version r2012b, python version 2.7

Edit 2: I probably found why matlab closes. I am calling DispatchEx from a GUI built in wxPython, which contains a mainloop. I tried with a simple script without GUI and it all works fine. I am leaving this question open here if someone has the same problem or has found a solution.

Comment: Has this been resolved?

Comment: Added an answer since I found the answer from other questions and approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QA [Calling MATLAB functions from python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883189/calling-matlab-functions-from-python) indicates there should not be a problem. This [Matlab page](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102255-how-can-i-make-a-dcom-server-instance-of-matlab-visible) suggests you might have to configure your Matlab installation to accept being opened this way.

Note: It is not likely that the 'matlab.application', which is a COM server object, has anything to do with the matlab wrapper you found out about; the wrapper is just an executable. One of the matlab libraries has been registered as the COM server for matlab.application.

Answer (score 0):

use `Dispatch`

```
def execute_matlab_command(command):
    handle = win32com.client.Dispatch('matlab.application')
    handle.visible = True
    # By using print I know that the handle is valid here
    handle.Execute(command)
```

I haven't used `DispatchEx` before, but I guarantee you `Dispatch` will work.

Comment: Matlab starts but shuts down when it is fully loaded, without running the command. Dispatch dont autoclose?