# Python and call Matlab script outside of Python with arguments

Tags: python, matlab, arguments, subprocess, popen

I feel like i am almost there but need the extra push!  I am trying to call a MATLAB script from Python (I'm not worried about the output of the MATLAB script - it runs independently).  However, i must be able to send an input into the MATLAB script from python.

Right now I have(in python):

```
myvartoinput = 55
cmd = 'myscript.m'
process = Popen(["matlab", "-nosplash", "-nodesktop", "-r",  cmd], shell=True)  
process.communicate()

# Also, how do i 'exit' the MATLAB so it doesn't continue to run
```

I am not sure how to add "myvartoinput" into the 'myscript.m' file.  Also, did I call the script correctly?  Finally, i would like it to "exit" so it doesn't stay open in the background on my pc.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883189/calling-matlab-functions-from-python

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it differently:

```
import os 
import subprocess
myvartoinput = 55

subprocess.call(['matlab', '-wait','-nosplash','-nodesktop','-r','myscript(\'%s\')' %(myvartoinput )])
```

Arguments:

'-wait' - python waits till Matlab executes script and continues;

'-nodesktop' - only matlab command window is called;

'-nosplash' - suppresses the display of the splash screen;

'-r' - argument after which follows name of a script

More info here: http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/startup-options.html